# Get content based on browsing history in analytics

Tags: xdb, personalization

I have a scenario where a client wants to build a list of articles based on the user's browsing history stored in analytics. So performing a search, but with criteria based on "because you viewed X, Y, and Z pages."

I would think this is something done with analytics that isn't too difficult, but I haven't seen a good sample in my searching. I also imagine this is heavily reliant on the client tagging their data appropriately as well.

Are there any good primers on this type of functionality, both from the programmatic as well as the authoring sides?

Comment: [Coveo for Sitecore](https://www.coveo.com/en/solutions/coveo-for-sitecore) is a Sitecore module that brings this functionality to Sitecore. Among other things, it allows to log all your visitors page views in the Coveo Cloud Usage Analytics service. It does not use xDB for that feature. Then, when a visitor comes to the website, its current session viewing history is compared to the visit history of previous visitors using machine learning and the current visitor is proposed pages he could be interested in as next steps. They call that "Machine Learning-Powered Recommendations". You can see a

Comment: We've done something similar in the hackathon 2017. Maybe this article can help: https://kverheire.blogspot.com/2017/03/incorporating-xdb-analytics-information.html (some things might have changed since though)